# Sum Of a column of generic list

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, generic-list

i have list of string like this :

```
Dim totalPrice As New List(Of Integer)
```

how can i get sum of column(0) (C# or VB) ?
thanks

Comment: Might be silly question, but why use **List(Of String)**??

Comment: I did edit question . can you use better word instead 'silly' ?

Comment: Your question is vague and references different things. A list has no columns. A list is exactly that, a linear set of items. Also, how do you intend to get a total of strings? How are the strings formatted? Consider revising your question.

Comment: Maybe you can explain your goal in more detail. As it is, I don't know what your question means.

Comment: `List(Of String)` has no columns. There is only ever one "item" per "row", so there's no concept of "columns"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#:

```
var lst = new List<int>();
lst.Sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

In `C#` do the following to conver the string list into a int list and the sum it.

```
List<string> list_str = new List<string>();
...
var list_int = list_str.Select( (x)=>int.Parse(x) );
int sum = list_int.Sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to Sum a string but if it where a list of Integers

```
List<int> totalPrice = new List<int>();
var SumOftotalPrice = (from s in totalPrice
                       select s).Sum();
```

Comment: you can call `Sum()` etc function directly on lists and other `IEnumerables`

Comment: i know, its just for completeness sake

Answer (score 2):

may be this should help

> int sum =
>   stringList.ConvertAll(Convert.ToInt32).Sum();